# Filtar datos con dos EditText en un ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

En mi aplicación Android estoy intentando filtrar fecha en un ListView obtenidos los datos cargados en una BD, en el primer EditText pongo una fecha inicio y en el otro EditText agrego otra fecha que es el final quiero que se muestre en el ListView dentro de ese rango de los dos EditText ingresados, quisiera saber si es posible filtrar el segundo campo sin que se borre el primero así como si alguien le diera un rango especifico y me muestre dentro de ese rango en este ListView, he intentado agregar `for` sobre esta función `beforeTextChanged()` y los demás pero no logro funcionarlo.

Mi código es la siguiente:

1. Agrego la fecha con este código:

```
fechainico.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.edtinicio:
                    showDatePickerDialog1();
                }
            }
        });

        fechafin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.edtfinal:
                        showDatePickerDialog2();
                }
            }
        });
```

2. Estoy usando esta función para el filtro:

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lista);
        listaResultado.setAdapter(adaptador);

fechainico.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                adaptador.getFilter().filter(s);
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                //adaptador.getFilter().filter(s);
            }
        });

fechafin.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                for (int i = 0; i < adaptador.getCount(); i++) {
                    adaptador.getFilter().filter(s);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Pues, ¿Por qué no creas un `Array` que busque tu `String` desde un mètodo?

Comment: Si lo he intentado con un Array y me resulto útil su respuesta, muchas gracias Saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que yo haría, y quizá es la forma más larga, es lo siguiente.

Crearía un `Array` con la consulta:

```
public ArrayList buscarPorFecha(String fechaInicio, String fechaFin) {
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList<>();
        this.openReadableDB();
        String[] campos = new String[]{ConstantsBD.CLI_ID, ConstantsBD.CLI_NOMBRE + todos los campos de tu taba};
        String where = ConstantsBD.INICIO + " like '%" + fechaInicio + "%' AND " + ConstantsBD.FIN + " like '%" + fechaFin + "%' AND ";
        Cursor c = db.query(ConstantsBD.TABLA_CLIENTES, campos, where, null, null, null, null);
        try {
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                Clientes cliente = new Clientes();
                cliente.setId(c.getInt(0));
                cliente.setNombre(c.getString(1));
                + todos los datos de tu clase
                list.add(cliente);
            }
        } finally { c.close(); }
        this.closeDB();
        return list;
    }
```

Hecho esto, suponiendo que tenemos un botòn por ahì hacemos que cargue el `ListView`:

```
tuBoton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                tuArrayDeLaClase=new TuDBSQLite(TuActividad.this).buscarPorFecha(tuEditext1.getText().toString(), tuEditText2.getText().toString());
                tuListView.setAdapter(new tuAdaptador(TuActividad.this, tuArrayDeLaClase));
            }
        });
```